# Apache authenticate all paths (incl. root "/") execept one

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

I try to restrict access to a certain virtual host for all paths (including test.tonnerklaps.local). The only public accessible path should be "/webhook/bitbucket".

This is my host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.tonnerklaps.local
  DocumentRoot /srv/satisfy/public
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/test.tonnerklaps.local.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/test.tonnerklaps.local-key.pem

  <Location "/">
    LogMessage "L root %{REQUEST_URI}"
    <RequireAll>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Resticted Access"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwd/passwords"
      Require user packagist
    </RequireAll>
  </Location>
  <Location "/webhook/bitbucket">
    LogMessage "L webhook %{REQUEST_URI}"
    Require all granted
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that i'm asked to authenticate on "/webhook/bitbucket" too. Interestingly it seems to have something to do with "/".

Because this is working as expected:

```
  <Location "/admin">
    LogMessage "L admin %{REQUEST_URI}"
    <RequireAll>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Resticted Access"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwd/passwords"
      Require user packagist
    </RequireAll>
  </Location>
  <Location "/admin/configuration">
    LogMessage "L admin.configuration %{REQUEST_URI}"
    Require all granted
  </Location>
```

But what really surprises me is that the following is also not working. Although the else path never gets logged i get the authentication prompt on "/webhook/bitbucket".

```
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/webhook/bitbucket'">
    LogMessage "If %{REQUEST_URI}"
    Require all granted
  </If>
  <Else>
    LogMessage "Else %{REQUEST_URI}"
    <RequireAll>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Resticted Access"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwd/passwords"
      Require user packagist
    </RequireAll>
  </Else>
```

Any ideas on this?

I try to run satisfy (`composer create-project playbloom/satisfy`) on Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu). I get the same behavior also with another php application (concreteCMS).

**Update**
I tested `<Location>` without the app (just created the folder structure and index.php files). This is working. Anyhow still no clue why it's not working in the app an also why the `<If>` is not working.

**Update 2**
This is the latest config i'm using.

```
  <Location "/webhook/bitbucket">
    AuthMerging Off
    LogMessage "L webhook %{REQUEST_URI}"
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
  </Location>
  <Location "/">
    LogMessage "L root %{REQUEST_URI}"
    AuthMerging Off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Resticted Access"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwd/passwords"
    Require user packagist
  </Location>
```

**Update 3**
There is this .htaccess-File inside satisfy/public Folder. It must have something to do with this, but i can't wrap my head around it yet.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews +Indexes
    
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Set the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache as environment variable.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content.
    # We only do this redirect on the initial rewrite to prevent endless redirect loops.
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists or should exist, simply serve it.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/favicon.ico [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/robots.txt
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

#Compress JSON files
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <IfModule mod_filter.c>
            SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried both orders. If i browse to `/` only the location with "/" gets logged/called. If i browse to `/webhook/bitbucket` both locations get logged. So to me i would make more sense if the `grant` statement was after auth. Somehow grant seems to be weaker. But all this should not matter in my last example, which is also not working.

Comment: Thing is, /webhook/bitbucket is not an actual directory, it's only a route in the app. I tested it nevertheless but to no avail. I only ever hit `<Directory "/srv/satisfy/public">`. But i did some further testing. See updated question.

Comment: **1.** Removed `<RequireAll>` to no avail

**2.** `Require` seems to be valid inside `<Location>`, it's basically working (as i stated in my question), it's not working on "/".

**3.** `AuthType None` did not change anything

**4.** No .htaccess present.

**5.** Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: jop, `AutoMerging Off`, in both `<Location>` sections, also changed order, to no avail :(

Comment: Tested on my site, using ubuntu 20.04 and your configuration works, so you should check your apache configuration to find out if there are any directive that could explain the wrong behavior. Some alias or rewrite rule that manipulate url. Also enable log at debug level and check how request are handled

Comment: Did you test with an actual php webapp? What apache version do you have? What directives exactly did you use? Is it also working with `<If>`?
As it is basically working (not with php webapp and not if i want to authenticate "/"), i have no idea for what i should be looking in the apache config.

Comment: Set up a new vm, installed apache2 (2.4.41), unzip, php7.4, composer (from https://getcomposer.org/download/), satisfy (the webapp it is all about as stated in my question), a2enmod log_debug and rewrite. There is a rewrite in the app (/webhook/bitbucket -> /index.php/webhook/bitbucket, without mod_rewrite the first path is not callable) but it's in the app and i don't understand how it's interfering with the vh config as the $REQUEST_URI i'm logging is /webhock/bitbucket. Config i'm using is "Update 2" in the question. This is not working.

Comment: I have a php site in ubuntu, to verify I insert in my virtualhost two Location one with "/" and one with "/mysitefolder" in this two location I insert  "Require all granted" and "Require all denied" just to see if I can go to "/mysitefolder" and I can do that. you should check all active configuration in enabled site folder and apache2.conf. If your app has a configuration file be sure that your file is alphabetically lower than app

Comment: Lety thanks for sticking with this. See Update 3 in my question. Like you suspected it must have something to do with the rewrites... But this goes over my head at the moment.

Comment: try with "LogLevel debug rewrite:trace5" this should give you information on rewrite manipulation. As I can see, the rewrite rule check if there is a prefix and save it in BASE environment (in your case it should be empty) and any url that doesn't have a file on filesystem are handled by the last rule (RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [QSA,L]) so it is handled by "/index.php". so where did you see the rewrite rule that redirect /webhook/bitbucket -> /index.php/webhook/bitbucket ?

Comment: hey lety, thanks to your last comment (LogLevel...) i gained much more insight at how things are working. there is no solution to my problem, as the request gets checked before and after each rewrite (which makes perfect sense). so path "/webhook/bitbucket" gets rewritten to just index.php and after this rewrite it seems there is no possibility to check what the original request was ($REQUEST_URI is no longer "/webhook/bitbucket"). at least this is the case on apache level, the app seems to somehow to get the request uri. still not entirely sure how this part is working.

Comment: so i ended up disabling .htaccess and copied the logic over to my vh config. whit that i have total control over it and it should be update save. i now prevent index.php/webhook/bitbucket from being rewritten and pass it directly to the app. i allow unauthenticated access only to this path.

Comment: good! You should write your own answer in order to help other that will get this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no solution to my problem, as the request gets checked before and after each rewrite (which makes perfect sense). So path "/webhook/bitbucket" gets rewritten to just index.php and after this rewrite it looks like there is no possibility to check what the original request was ($REQUEST_URI is no longer "/webhook/bitbucket"). At least this is the case on apache level. The app seems somehow to get the request uri all the same. Still not entirely sure how this part is working. If anyone could provide more information about this, i'd be happy to hear it.

I ended up disabling .htaccess and merge it with my vh config. So i can prevent the webhook path to be rewritten and can allow unrestricted access only to this path. I then call it like `index.php/webhook/bitbucket`. this is also update save as long as there are no relevant changes to the .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName packagist.lemonbrain.ch
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/satisfy/public
    SSLEngine on

    <Directory "/var/www/html/satisfy/public">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Resticted Access"
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile "/var/www/passwd/passwords"

        <RequireAny>
          # only allow unauthenticated access to the bitbucket webhook
          Require expr "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/index.php/webhook/bitbucket'"
          Require user packagist
        </RequireAny>

        # disable .htaccess in satisfy/public
        AllowOverride None
        RewriteEngine On

        # do not rewrite the bitbucket webhook (leave index.php) for the require above to work
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "=/index.php/webhook/bitbucket"
        RewriteRule .* - [END]

        #################################################################################
        # this is the content of the .htaccess in satify/public                         #
        # so if there is something not working after updating satisfy check and compare #
        #################################################################################
Options -MultiViews +Indexes
        # RewriteEngine On

        # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        # Set the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache as environment variable.
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content.
        # We only do this redirect on the initial rewrite to prevent endless redirect loops.
        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

        # If the requested filename exists or should exist, simply serve it.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/favicon.ico [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/robots.txt
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [QSA,L]

        #Compress JSON files
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
                <IfModule mod_filter.c>
                    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
                    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
                </IfModule>
            </IfModule>
        </IfModule>
        ###########################
        # end of copied .htaccess #
        ###########################
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```